Visual Studio 2022, как получить диаграмму классов для проекта WEB API ASP.Net
Конструктор классов установлен, но для текущего проекта WEB API ASP.Net нигде не вижу возможности сделать диаграмму классов для своего проекта. Через кнопку добавить - пункта типа "схема" или "диаграмма" отсутствуют. При этом в той же студии для консольного проекта такой пункт есть. Как сделать автоматически схему для WEB API ASP.Net?
